# Looping in parallel

Tags: go, parallel-processing, goroutine

I new to `golang` and I am reading the example from the book *gopl*.

There is an example of making thumbnails in parallel:

```
func makeThumbnails6(filenames <-chan string) int64 {
    sizes := make(chan int64)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup // number of working goroutines
    for f := range filenames {
        wg.Add(1)
        // worker
        go func(f string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            thumb, err := thumbnail.ImageFile(f)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
            }
            info, _ := os.Stat(thumb) // OK to ignore error
            sizes <- info.Size()
        }(f)
    }

    // closer
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(sizes)
    }()

    var total int64
    for size := range sizes {
        total += size
    }
    return total
}
```

My doubt is that will it be possible that the closer passes the `wg.Wait()` before all files are processed?

E.g if `work1` finishes its job and decreases `wg` to zero, then some magical scheduling happens and `close` get the time to run and close the channel?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: there is no way panic happening, but in my opinion, you dont need that, garbage collector will do it for you

Answer (score 4):

`wg.Wait` won't return until all the worker goroutines are done. When `wg.Wait` is called in the closer goroutine, you've already called `wg.Add(1)` once for each worker goroutine, so `wg.Wait` won't return until `wg.Done` has been called the same number of times, and that happens when the goroutine function returns. Therefore, the closer goroutine won't call `close` until all the worker goroutines have finished what they're doing.

As you said, it is theoretically possible that `wg`'s counter may reach 0 while still in the loop that creates the workers, but once the loop finishes, the counter will only be 0 once all the goroutines have finished. Since you aren't starting the closer goroutine until the loop completes, there's no danger of `wg.Wait` returning before all the workers are done.